# php ssh phpseclib output over multiple lines

Tags: php, ssh, output, phpseclib

I would like to execute commands on remote server via ssh and i use phpseclib. 
If i run the command, all the output is in one line (because its a string).

I would have the same output as in the local shell

Current var_dump():

`string(291) "Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-04-10 10:08 CEST Nmap scan report for dns.google (8.8.8.8) Host is up (0.0037s latency). Not shown: 998 filtered ports PORT STATE SERVICE 53/tcp open domain 443/tcp open https Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.59 seconds "`

Current Output:

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-04-10 10:14 CEST Nmap scan report for dns.google (8.8.8.8) Host is up (0.0036s latency). Not shown: 998 filtered ports PORT STATE SERVICE 53/tcp open domain 443/tcp open https Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.50 seconds
```

Expected Output:

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-04-10 10:14 CEST
Nmap scan report for dns.google (8.8.8.8)
Host is up (0.0037s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
53/tcp  open  domain
443/tcp open  https
```

Current Code:

```
<?php 

     include 'vendor/autoload.php';

     $ssh = new \phpseclib3\Net\SSH2('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');
     if (!$ssh->login('root', 'password')) {
         exit('Login Failed');
     }
     echo $ssh->exec('nmap 8.8.8.8');

?>
```

Comment: Try passing the output of `$ssh->exec()` through `nl2br()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<pre>`

```
<?php 

     include 'vendor/autoload.php';

     $ssh = new \phpseclib3\Net\SSH2('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');
     if (!$ssh->login('root', 'password')) {
         exit('Login Failed');
     }
     echo "<pre>";
     echo $ssh->exec('nmap 8.8.8.8');
     echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: This solution works, yes. In this case the method nl2br would also do the trick. In general, you should avoid writing HTML Layout within PHP in multiple lines. In the above example the PRE Tag is rendered in three calls. If one call breaks, the HTML would be broken. You could do it like this in one call: printf('<pre>%s</pre>', $ssh->exec('nmap 8.8.8.8'));. But the best solution would be to use HTML templates and seperate PHP and HTML. But maybe this is just a small test script and a template engine would totaly overdone.

Comment: I agree with the above, but additionally i think `nl2br` should be the preferred solution here if the output is HTML